# Convert Multiple Selection DidSelectRowAtIndexPath from Objective C to Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am in the process of converting my app from Objective C to Swift.  I doing well in all areas with this exception.  In my objective c file I have a UITableView that allows multiple selections.  When the user selects a cell, information from that object is stored in an array. and when the user clicks the cell again, that object is removed.  I am trying to figure out how this works in Swift 3 and I can add the object, but I just cannot seem to figure out how to remove that object from the array.  Please advise.  Below is my code from Objective C that I am trying to convert over.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        RibbonsInfo *ribbonsInfo = [ribbonsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [ribbonTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (ribbonTableView.allowsMultipleSelection == YES) {
            if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

                [selectedRibbons addObject:ribbonsInfo];

            }
            else {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                [selectedRibbons removeObject:ribbonsInfo];
            }
        }
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift, you can only remove items from an `Array` by using its `index`. So you need to get the index of that object inside that array, then call `selectedRibbons.remove(at: index)`.

For example.

```
var array = Array<String>()

array.append("apple")

array.append("banana")

array.append("orange")

print(array) // ["apple", "banana", "orange"]

if let index = array.index(of: "banana") {

    array.remove(at: index)
}

print(array) // ["apple", "orange"]
```